# Не работает плавная прокрутка к якорю в Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, прокрутка, firefox

У меня есть код плавной прокрутки к якорю, работает во всех браузера и с мобилки тоже, кроме FireFox. В чем может быть проблема?

```
var linkNav = document.querySelectorAll('[href^="#"]'), //выбираем все ссылки к якорю на странице
    V = 0.2;  // скорость, может иметь дробное значение через точку (чем меньше значение - тем больше скорость)
for (var i = 0; i < linkNav.length; i++) {
    linkNav[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) { //по клику на ссылку
        e.preventDefault(); //отменяем стандартное поведение
        var w = window.pageYOffset,  // производим прокрутка прокрутка
            hash = this.href.replace(/[^#]*(.*)/, '$1');  // к id элемента, к которому нужно перейти
        var t = (document.querySelector(hash)) ? document.querySelector(hash).getBoundingClientRect().top - 20: null; // отступ от окна браузера до id
        var start = null;
        requestAnimationFrame(step);  // подробнее про функцию анимации [developer.mozilla.org]
        function step(time) {
            if (start === null) start = time;
            var progress = time - start,
                r = (t < 0 ? Math.max(w - progress / V, w + t) : Math.min(w + progress / V, w + t));
            window.scrollTo(0, r);
            if (r != w + t) {
                requestAnimationFrame(step);
                location.hash = hash;
            } else {
                location.hash = hash; // URL с хэшем
            }
        }
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: Может так получится `mozRequestAnimationFrame()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если скорость прокрутки неважна, предлагаю использовать вам нативное свойство плавной прокрутки: `scroll-behavior: smooth;`. Такая плавная прокрутка работает во всех современных браузерах, а в старых браузерах прокрутка будет мгновенной.  Причем данный метод полностью работает без JS (а JS здесь добавлен только для того, что вам необходимо смещение в 20 пикселей для каждого якоря). Кроме того данный способ учитывает синхронизацию с анимационными кадрами браузера (animation frames).

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('[href^="#"]');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var el = document.querySelector(this.hash);
    if (el) {
      window.scrollTo(0, el.getBoundingClientRect().top - 20);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  }, false);
}
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

p { 
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#anchor-01">Anchor 01</a></li>
  <li><a href="#anchor-02">Anchor 02</a></li>
  <li><a href="#anchor-03">Anchor 03</a></li>
</ul>

<p id="anchor-01">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
<p id="anchor-02">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
<p id="anchor-03">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
```